# CSS styling of Shiny runtime RMarkdown document with a For Loop

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, runtime

I'm creating an R Markdown file with runtime Shiny that dynamically creates content using a for loop. I've managed to get this working (example below) but have run into a problem when it comes to applying CSS/other elements to the output.

What I'm trying to get to is a final section (Fruit Info in the example below) to displays text, images, links in a styled, coloured box for each instance in the loop. I can get this working with a 'normal' Rmarkdown file rendered to HTML, but can't seem to replicate this with Shiny.

Here's the full code for a replicable example of the Markdown/Shiny. Further down is what I've done with Markdown/nonShiny

I'm using renderPrint because renderText didn't seem to return anything.

````
```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "14/07/2021"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    toc: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
##CREATE DATAFRAME
fruit = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Orange")
size = c("One", "Two", "Three", "One", "One", "Two")
country = c("UK", "UK", "ES", "DE", "UK", "DE")
df <- data.frame(fruit, size, country)
df$description <- paste(df$fruit, "from", df$country, "with a size", df$size)
```
````

##### Add Select Inputs

````
```{r user_select_project, echo=FALSE}
fluidRow(column(4, selectInput("fruit", "Choose Fruit:", choices = sort(unique(df$fruit)), multiple = TRUE, selected = sort(unique(df$fruit)))),
column(4, selectInput("size", "Choose Size:", choices = sort(unique(df$size)), multiple = TRUE, selected = sort(unique(df$size)))),
         column(4, selectInput("country", "Choose Country:", choices = sort(unique(df$country)), multiple = TRUE, selected = sort(unique(df$country)))))
```
````

##### Create reactive drame for data table

````
```{r fruitdata, echo=FALSE}
fruit_data <- reactive({
  df %>%
    filter(fruit %in% input$fruit) %>%   
    filter(size %in% input$size) %>% 
    filter(country %in% input$country) 
})
```
````

##### Render Datatable

````
```{r fruittable, echo=FALSE}
renderDT({
  fruit_data_new <- fruit_data()
  fruit_data_table <- fruit_data_new[, 1:3]
  DT::datatable(fruit_data_table,
                options = list(pageLength = 5), 
                rownames = FALSE,
                colnames = c("Fruit", "Size", "Country"), escape = F)  
})
```
````

##### Render Fruit Info - PROBLEM IS HERE

Based on your selection the following items are returned

````
```{r myfruit, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
fruit_data_display <- reactive({
  df %>%
    filter(fruit %in% input$fruit) %>%  
    filter(size %in% input$size) %>% 
    filter(country %in% input$country) 
})

fruit_data_template <- "%s is the fruit
The size is %s
It comes from %s

"

renderPrint({
  fruit_data_display <- fruit_data_display()
  fruit_data_template <- fruit_data_template
  if (nrow(fruit_data_display) < 1) {
    "Nothing matches your current selection"
  } else {
    for (i in seq(nrow(fruit_data_display))) {
      current <- fruit_data_display[i, ]
      cat(sprintf(fruit_data_template, current$fruit, current$size, current$country))
    }
  }
  
})
```
````

All of the above works but (because, I guess, I'm using renderPrint?), the output is just basic text. As mentioned above, using renderText did not return anything. Adding style elements to the template simple returned the code in the output.

What I'm *trying* to get to is a series of boxes with elements styled.

Here's the code for how I've got that working in a standard Markdown doc rendered in HTML - this is using slightly different data, but it's same idea. With the code below I managed to make some text hyperlinks, some bold, and also to include images. I'd like to achieve the same thing with the runtime shiny code above.

````
```
##This goes in the main body:
<style>

div.blue { background-color:#add8e6; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px;}

</style>

##This goes in as code
## 1: create data
input <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[1:4],
  data = runif(n = 4),
  text = replicate(4, paste(sample(x = LETTERS, size = 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input$image <- c("imageA.png", "imageB.png", "imageC.png", "imageD.png")
input$image_caption <- c("Image A Caption", "Image B Caption", "Image C Caption", "Image D Caption")
input$hyperlink <- "https://www.bbc.co.uk"

##2: Create a template
template <- "#### This is section %s with automated styling applied

<div class = 'blue'>
Section <b>data</b> is now in a blue box `%0.2f`.
</div>
Additional section <b>text</b> is now a hyperlink to the BCU website: [%s.](%s){target='_blank'}

And we now have <b>images</b> with their <b>image_captions</b> underneath.
![%s](/img/%s)

"

#3 create a for loop

for (i in seq(nrow(input))) {
  current <- input[i, ]
  cat(sprintf(template, current$name, current$data, current$text, current$hyperlink, current$image_caption, current$image))
}
```
````

In the standard Rmarkdown, this renders like the attached image:
[image]

Hopefully I've explained the issue correctly, and the code provided enables a replicable example. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to solve this following a fair amount of trial and error, in case anyone is interested.

The solution I've found is to create a list with a for loop, then unlist this before passing the result(s) to the HTML output handled by renderUI.

This enables some basic styling inside the creation of **text_output**, such as bold text, line breaks and a href external links.

FYI...the rest of the original code is the same, except a new variable (**web**) has been added to the dummy **fruit** data frame in order to test external links.

One thing I seem unable to do with this solution so far is to include images using img src. I'll post a new question about that (or update this one if I'm able to figure it out).

```
renderUI({
  if (nrow(fruit_data_display()) < 1) {
    HTML(paste("<b>", "Nothing matches your current selection", "</b>"))
  } else {
  text_output <- list()
  fruit_data_display <- fruit_data_display()
  for(i in(nrow(fruit_data_display))) {
    text_output[[i]] <- paste("<h4 style='color:blue;'>", fruit_data_display$fruit, "</h4>", 
                              "<p style='background-color: powderblue;'>",
                              "<b>Description:</b>",
                              "The size of the fruit is", fruit_data_display$size, "<br>",
                              "The country it comes from is", "<a href='", fruit_data_display$web,
                              "'target='_blank'>", fruit_data_display$country ,"</a>", "<p>")
    text_output <- paste(unlist(text_output))
  }
    HTML(paste(text_output))
  }
  
})
```